# jQUery script working on Chrome and IE but not working in Mozila Firefox

Tags: jquery

I made a script for a menu that got submenu. In Chrome the script is working fine but in Firefox its closing the menu and not opening it at all.

```
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery('li.otchet-open').children().hide();
  jQuery('li.otchet-open').addClass('closed');
  jQuery('li.otchet-open').click(function(e) {
    if(event.target == event.currentTarget) {
      if(jQuery(this).hasClass('closed')) {

        jQuery(this).children().show();
        jQuery(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');

      } else if(jQuery('li.otchet-open').hasClass('opened')) {

        jQuery(this).children().hide();
        jQuery(this).removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');

      }

      e.stopPropagation();

    }
  });

});
```

HTML PART

```
<ul>
  <li class="otchet-open closed">ОТНОСНО: Приемане на Общинска програма за оптимизация на училищната мрежа в Община Шумен през 2017 година
    <ul style="display: none;">
      <li class="child"><a href="/decisions/17488.pdf">Решение </a></li>
      <li class="child"><a href="/decisions/1748801.pdf">Общинска програма </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Please post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: post your markup

Comment: I didnt get any errors in the developer console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
jQuery('li.otchet-open').click(function(e) {
     if(event.target == event.currentTarget) {
```

Change that to:

```
jQuery('li.otchet-open').click(function(e) {
     if(e.target == e.currentTarget) {
```

```js
jQuery(function() {

  jQuery('li.otchet-open').children().hide();
  jQuery('li.otchet-open').addClass('closed');
  jQuery('li.otchet-open').click(function(e) {
      if(e.target == e.currentTarget) {
          if(jQuery(this).hasClass('closed')) {

              jQuery(this).children().show();
              jQuery(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');

          } else if(jQuery('li.otchet-open').hasClass('opened')) {

              jQuery(this).children().hide();
              jQuery(this).removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');

          }
          e.stopPropagation();
      }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
    <li class="otchet-open closed">ОТНОСНО: Приемане на Общинска програма за оптимизация на училищната мрежа в Община
        Шумен през 2017 година

        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li class="child"><a href="/decisions/17488.pdf">Решение </a></li>
            <li class="child"><a href="/decisions/1748801.pdf">Общинска програма </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```